# How do I convert these 4 SQL tables into OO Classes (Java or C#) but not with NHibernate/LINQ?

Tags: c#, java, sql, vb.net, oop

**newbie** here. I am trying to learn OOD/OOP and read on the net that I am not supposed convert SQL tables into classes. But I cannot find an explanation why not to do it or which tables to skip. So I made an web application based on the below diagram. It works perfectly well. But I do not use OO. Would someone please explain simply which table should not be mapped into a class and why not. Thank you for your time. 
P.S. Please do not use LINQ or NHibernate, etc as I do not understand them. I just need to understand the OOD.

[image: SQL Tables Diagram]

Comment: Why do you want to skip some table? All four seem to deserve being mapped into classes...

Comment: You must not *automatically* convert tables into objects. Think of the class hierarchy that your application needs and map those into tables. OOP is not just 'having classes' and using them, but dessigning them. How can you understand ORM without properly understanding OOP?

Comment: Thank you @SJuan76. I ended up with only 2 classes for my main use case of making a booking, and not one class per table. I gave you a point for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When designing an application in .NET (and probably most other languages), every table needed by the application becomes its own class, but you can certainly have more classes that are not mapped to table.

With your program's requirements in hand, you need to design the database layer (i.e. your tables) to persist any data you want saved in a database. Then - for a small project - each table becomes a class automatically and you can start building more classes to manage these "model" or "entity" classes. Classes mapped to tables are often called entities or models. Classes that are not mapped are just called classes.

So, in your example, you have four tables, so you will have at LEAST four model classes. You would then design additional non-model classes (as needed and makes sense) to manage your model classes appropriately through your program.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to understand OOP DON'T start with the database. The fact that you are seeing everywhere the 'conversion' of tables into classes is just an unfortunate side effect of demonstrating a certain ORM (Object Relational Mapper) like Entity Framework. Those are demos for a certain library and not for OOP.

So, first things first, ignore the database. ALL of it. It's unfortunate that MS pushes that damn EF everywhere as 'look how easy you can do web apps'. An ORM is an advanced topic. You should learn the basics of OOP (with C#), that is understand what an object is compared to a class, what encapsulation , inheritance , polymorphism are and about SOLID principles (google about them, you'll find lots of articles and video presentations).

Only after you understood those, try a database and start with basic ado.net . And only after you have a clear understanding of it, go read about ORMs. In fact, before that you should read about Design Patterns a bit.

You really have to have a clear understanding of all these concepts. FOr now, I think everything is very confusing to you, because the majority of tutorials target a certain funcitonality without regard to proper application layering or responsibilities. Everything is mixed together and as a beginner,you're left with the impression that this is the way you have to do things.

Comment: Thank you @MikeSW. I applied it. I ended up with only 2 classes for my main use case of making a booking, and not one class per table.